# If the datetime is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 then change to NOW();?

Tags: mysql

The question says it all. Basically a function similar to `IFNULL`, but `IF(PARAMTER)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL `IF()` function will do what we need:

```
IF(mycol='0000-00-00 00:00:00',NOW(),mycol)
```

This is equivalent to (the more verbose, and more ANSI-standards compliant):

```
CASE WHEN mycol = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN NOW() ELSE mycol END
```

Answer (score 1):

For selecting:

```
SELECT CASE YourDate WHEN '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN NOW() ELSE YourDate END 
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple update statement work?

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = NOW() WHERE `column` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```